# scipy.interpolate.interp1d 'kind' not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, interpolation

I'm experimenting with interpolate.interp1d but there is some strange behaviour with it. Here's the script:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)  
y = np.cos(-x**2/9.0)
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', x, f(x), '--')
plt.legend(['data', 'interp'], loc='best')
plt.show()
plt.pause(2**31-1)
```

But the result I'm getting is like I'm passing kind='linear'. In fact, no matter the parameter 'kind', the result is the same. Am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: since you have used only part of the example in the docs, you should get similar graphs as in the answer if you use the complete example, where indeed there are more points when plotting the result of the interpolation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only plotting it at the x values you're using to fit it, so you're only seeing the agreement there and lines drawn between those points.  If you plot it at more points between 0 and 10 (e.g. `np.linspace(0, 10, 100)`, you'll start to see the difference:

[image: sample interpolation output]